# What can I say as a response to a rescheduled meeting by client?

Tags: email, meetings, email-etiquette

I requested a client to reschedule a meeting which we had arranged previously via email, I apologized for the inconvenience as well and they sent me below reply email:

> No inconvenience at all. We will reschedule for tomorrow. Take care

What can I send as a response to this? I thought just saying thank you is too short.
The client is Canadian, if that helps in some way.

P.S. I am not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 6):

Saying "Thank you" is exactly sufficient. It doesn't need to be more than acknowledgement of the change and the accommodation. Anything more than that will be more words than they will want to read for something that is already done.

Comment: Thank you for your input Joel! :)

Comment: Might work even better to open the meeting with verbal thanks (to show that you mean it) rather than responding electronically (which could be seen as perfunctory).  I still wouldn't spend more than a sentence on it, though.

Answer (score 6):

I think nothing need to be sent as a reply.

Canadian or not, the back and forth already happen and meeting rescheduled

Comment: Thank you for the input. I was doubtful whether I will be perceived as rude if I don't send a response.

Comment: I'd suggest that something does need to be sent back in order to confirm that the OP received the information that the meeting *has* been rescheduled

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to respond, there's no request, no issue, or question in their reply. They've politely acknowledged the need for a change of date so everythings all good, a 'Thank you' would be perfectly acceptable

If you really feel the need a longer reply just use something like:

> Thank you for being understanding about this change of date, I apologise for any inconvenience caused.
> Look forward to talking to you tomorrow

Comment: Thank you Elizabeth! :)

Comment: Please don't do the reply, let alone the longer version. With this reply, it may provide the impression that you did not bother to read their previous email where they mentioned it was not an inconvenience, for which you already apologized. Be happy that they rescheduled and move on.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I wouldn't send that reply myself, simply providing an alternative if they felt like they needed to

Comment: Believe me, it's not needed.